# How to check whether specific entries exist in pandas dataframe and add new entries?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of confusion matrix grouping (either tp, fp, fn, tn), model name (the example below has 2 models, but in reality this is a variable amount and much larger), and proportion (proportion of examples in that given model + confusion matrix grouping, eg. the proportion of examples for model1 that are tp). The dataframe look something like this, but again this is made up and much smaller.

```
confusion_matrix_group   |  model   | proportion
TP                          Model1       0.73
TN                          Model1       0.27
FN                          Model2       0.24
TP                          Model2       0.58
TN                          Model2       0.18
...
```

As you can see, a given model's TP+FP+FN+TN proportions will sum up to 1. However, as shown in the examples, a model may not have all 4 groupings (only TP/TN for model1 and FN/TP/TN for model2). I want to go through and fill in any missing groups to have the grouping, model, and 0.0 for the proportion. The example above would become like this:

```
confusion_matrix_group   |  model   | proportion
TP                          Model1       0.73
TN                          Model1       0.27
FN                          Model2       0.24
TP                          Model2       0.58
TN                          Model2       0.18
FP                          Model1       0.0
FN                          Model1       0.0
FP                          Model2       0.0
...
```

I tried to apply the following code, but for some reason it doesn't go inside the if condition below which doesn't make sense to me. I doubt it's the best way to deal with this problem, so open to fixing this code or other suggestions altogether. Thanks for your help!

> ```
> for group in ['TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']:
>     for model in np.unique(df.model):
>         print([group, model])
>           # To fix: This condition doesn't work
>         if [group, model]) not in df[['confusion_matrix_group', 'model']].values:
>             # TODO: ADD NEW ROW to df
> ```

Comment: Try df.append() to add a new row to a df

Comment: Thanks! But I guess the bigger issue is that the condition `if [group, model]) not in df[['confusion_matrix_group', 'model']].values:` is not working as intended because it never enters the if statement. Not sure why though.

Comment: Convert `df[['confusion_matrix_group', 'model']].values` to list using `numpy.ndarray.tolist()` to make it an iterable list. See my answer below, if it helps

Answer (score 2):

One way is to brutally add all combinations first and then `drop_duplicates` (probably not performance friendly):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'confusion_matrix_group': {0: 'TP', 1: 'TN', 2: 'FN', 3: 'TP', 4: 'TN'},
                   'model': {0: 'Model1', 1: 'Model1', 2: 'Model2', 3: 'Model2', 4: 'Model2'},
                   'proportion': {0: 0.73, 1: 0.27, 2: 0.24, 3: 0.58, 4: 0.18}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[x, i, 0] for i in df["model"].unique() for x in ("TP","FP","FN","TN")],columns=df.columns)

print (pd.concat([df,df2],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(["model","confusion_matrix_group"],keep="first"))

#
   confusion_matrix_group   model  proportion
0                      TP  Model1        0.73
1                      TN  Model1        0.27
2                      FN  Model2        0.24
3                      TP  Model2        0.58
4                      TN  Model2        0.18
6                      FP  Model1        0.00
7                      FN  Model1        0.00
10                     FP  Model2        0.00
```

Another similar way by first creating a new column of concatenated name:

```
df["new"] = df["confusion_matrix_group"]+df["model"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[x, i, 0, x+i] for i in df["model"].unique() for x in ("TP","FP","FN","TN")],columns=df.columns)

print (pd.concat([df,df2.loc[~df2["new"].isin(df["new"])]],ignore_index=True))

#
  confusion_matrix_group   model  proportion       new
0                     TP  Model1        0.73  TPModel1
1                     TN  Model1        0.27  TNModel1
2                     FN  Model2        0.24  FNModel2
3                     TP  Model2        0.58  TPModel2
4                     TN  Model2        0.18  TNModel2
5                     FP  Model1        0.00  FPModel1
6                     FN  Model1        0.00  FNModel1
7                     FP  Model2        0.00  FPModel2
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps! But as you pointed out, I'm still wondering if there is a simpler and more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Would love to see a better answer too. Meanwhile I added another similar approach which should be faster by removing the need of `drop_duplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
names = ['confusion_matrix_group','model']
mind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN'], df['model'].unique()], names=names)
df.set_index(names).reindex(mind, fill_value=0).reset_index()
df

  confusion_matrix_group   model  proportion
0                     TP  Model1        0.73
1                     TP  Model2        0.58
2                     TN  Model1        0.27
3                     TN  Model2        0.18
4                     FP  Model1        0.00
5                     FP  Model2        0.00
6                     FN  Model1        0.00
7                     FN  Model2        0.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for group in ['TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']:
    for model in np.unique(df.model):
        if [group, model] not in df[['confusion_matrix_group', 'model']].values.tolist():
            df=df.append(pd.Series({'confusion_matrix_group': group, 'model': model, 'proportion': 0}),ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  confusion_matrix_group   model proportion
0                     TP  Model1       0.73
1                     TN  Model1       0.27
2                     FN  Model2       0.24
3                     TP  Model2       0.58
4                     TN  Model2       0.18
5                     FP  Model1          0
6                     FP  Model2          0
7                     FN  Model1          0
```

Comment: there are duplicates in the result

Comment: Sorry, I had missed 'not' in the if statement. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without double for loop using `df.groupby` and `apply`:

```py
def fill_models(grp):
    possible = ['TP', 'FP', 'TN', 'FN']
    model = grp['model']
    values = grp['confusion_matrix_group']
    if values.shape[0] < 4:
        grp = grp.append(pd.DataFrame([[group, model, 0.0] for group in possible if group not in values.values], columns=grp.columns))missing], columns=grp.columns))
    return grp

df_full = df.groupby('model')[df.columns].apply(fill_models).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This has the advantage of not checking any groupings that already exist and should operate fairly fast, though I have not done the timings on it

Comment: its the slowest of all answers

Comment: Interesting. Do you perhaps have the timings at hand?

Comment: yours: `4.96 ms ± 96.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`, second method of @Henry Yik `3.43 ms ± 73.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` (fastes besides his first answer which will slow down for bigger DFs)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to find missing group for each model using groupby and append it into df

```
groups = ['TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']
models = df['model'].unique()
df2 = df.groupby(['model']).apply(lambda x: list(set(groups) - set(x['confusion_matrix_group']))).explode()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'confusion_matrix_group'})
df2['proportion'] = 0
df.append(df2, sort=False)
```

It will give the following output

```
    confusion_matrix_group  model   proportion
0   TP  Model1  0.73
1   TN  Model1  0.27
2   FN  Model2  0.24
3   TP  Model2  0.58
4   TN  Model2  0.18
0   FP  Model1  0.00
1   FN  Model1  0.00
2   FP  Model2  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that sorting the dataframe is a good practice in this case. It helps to discriminate missing data and makes easier to apply 
changes across the dataframe structure.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['model','confusion_matrix_group'])

group = ['FN','FP','TN','TP'] #group options
row   = [] 

for c in list(df.groupby('model')['confusion_matrix_group']): #group by model

    if c[0]:

        y = list(set(group) - set(c[1])) #elements in group list not in confusion_matrix...         
        for val in y:
            data = [c[0],val,0.0]
            row.append(data)

#new matrix to append
dnew = pd.DataFrame(row,columns=['confusion_matrix_group','model','proportion'])

df = (df.append(dnew,ignore_index=False)).sort_values(by=['model','confusion_matrix_group'])

print(df)
    confusion_matrix_group   model  proportion
0                     FN    Model1        0.00
1                     FP    Model1        0.00
1                     TN    Model1        0.27
0                     TP    Model1        0.73
2                     FN    Model2        0.24
2                     FP    Model2        0.00
4                     TN    Model2        0.18
3                     TP    Model2        0.58
```